# Combine two Axios calls inside one useEffect with async/await

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, axios

I'm currently trying to understand how to work with async/await in React JS. In this demo app, I'm trying to get full border names of the chosen country by calling `https://restcountries.eu/`. I make first API call to get info about country and the second one to get full name of its borders since first API call returns
only short border names. I believe there is a way to combine those calls inside one `useEffect` however everything I tried gave me some sort of an error or getting stuck in infinite loop. What is the proper way to combine those calls with async/await approach?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";

const App = () => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [country, setCountry] = useState({});
    const [fullBorderNames, setFullBorderNames] = useState([]);

    //FIRST API CALL
    useEffect(() => {
        const source = Axios.CancelToken.source();
        const fetchData = async () => {
            setLoading(true);
            try {
                const response = await Axios(
                    `https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/canada?fullText=true`,
                    { cancelToken: source.token }
                );
                setCountry(response.data[0]);
            } catch (err) {
                if (Axios.isCancel(err)) {
                    console.log("Axios canceled");
                } else {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            }
        };
        fetchData();
        return () => source.cancel();
    }, []);

    //SECOND API CALL
    useEffect(() => {
        const source = Axios.CancelToken.source();
        let borders = [];
        if (country.borders) {
            const fetchData = async () => {
                try {
                    country.borders.forEach(async border => {
                        const response = await Axios(
                            `https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha?codes=${border}`,
                            { cancelToken: source.token }
                        );
                        borders.push(response.data[0].name);
                        if (borders.length === country.borders.length)
                            setFullBorderNames(borders);
                    });
                } catch (err) {
                    if (Axios.isCancel(err)) {
                        console.log("Axios canceled");
                    } else {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                }
                setLoading(false);
            };
            fetchData();
        }
        return () => source.cancel();
    }, [country.borders]);

    if (loading) {
        return <h2>Loading</h2>;
    } else {
        return (
            <>
                <pre>{JSON.stringify(country, null, 2)}</pre>
                <pre>{JSON.stringify(fullBorderNames, null, 2)}</pre>
            </>
        );
    }
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Which kind of errror do you get?

Comment: Code works fine for me. What's the error?

Comment: There is no error in the code I posted. This question is more about optimizing the code. Since second API call is depended on the first one, I'm trying to combine them into single call. First call gets country info and the second one need to get its full borders. In other words, there should be only one useEffect. I've tried to combine them but was constantly getting infinite loop or setFullBorderNames was not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply just make the requests right after the first one.

```
try {
    const response = await Axios(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/canada? 
                               fullText=true`, { cancelToken: source.token });
    const country = response.data[0];
    setCountry(country);
    /* all the other fetch calls*/
```

Can you tell me what kind of errors you get because I don't see an issue with doing them in the same useEffect? It just gets a little messy which can be refactored anyway.